# jekyll excerpt gives full post irrespective of first paragraph

Tags: jekyll

In `index.html` I used `{{ post.excerpt }}` in my jekyll site. This tag gives full content of post in index page instead of first paragraph. Did I miss any thing. I didn't use `<!-- more -->` in post and front matter or config file as excerpt seperator.

Comment: Did you look at this: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts?

Comment: I already know that. But can i use excerpt without excerpt seperator. I mean will it render first paragraph without except seperator?

Comment: The page says: "You can access a snippet of a posts’s content by using excerpt variable on a post. By default this is the first paragraph of content in the post, however it can be customized by setting a excerpt_separator variable in front matter or _config.yml." So yes.

Comment: did you solve it? I have exactly same problem

Answer (score 0):

> You can access a snippet of a posts’s content by using excerpt variable on a post. By default this is the first paragraph of content in the post, however it can be customized by setting a excerpt_separator variable in front matter or _config.yml.

Source: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the excerpt for the first post worked, but all subsequent excerpts were the whole post. This was true even if a subsequent post was a copy of the first. I was forced to configure a [excerpt_separator](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts).

```markdown
---
layout: post
title: <title>
excerpt_separator: <!-- excerpt -->
---

This is the first paragraph.

<!-- excerpt -->
```

Alternatively, define the excerpt in the front matter.

```markdown
---
layout: post
title: <title>
excerpt: <excerpt>
---
```